# How to create global variables functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I want to create a global function accessible everywhere in my script that would deal with a `Graph` object — constructing it, updating it, etc.

I made a function:

```
function GraphFactory(){
            this.initNames = function(nodes) {
                nodeNames = nodes;
            }
            this.getNodeNames = function() {
                return nodeNames;
            }
            this.addNameToNodeNames = function(name) {
                nodeNames.push(name);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Then when I try to populate it using

```
 GraphFactory.initNames(['hello','boo'])
```

It says `GraphFactory.initNames` is not a function...

How could I use this to populate that graph object with the node names and then get a list of them using `GraphFactory.getNodeNames()`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set a property on the class called `nodeNames`, then instantiate the object.

```js
function GraphFactory(){
    this.nodeNames= [];
    this.initNames = function(nodes) {
        this.nodeNames = nodes;
    }
    this.getNodeNames = function() {
        return this.nodeNames;
    }
    this.addNameToNodeNames = function(name) {
        this.nodeNames.push(name);
        return true;
    }
}

let graphFactory = new GraphFactory();
graphFactory.initNames(['hello','boo'])
console.log(graphFactory.getNodeNames());
```

Comment: Super, thank you very much, @Isaac! Could you please give me a reference as to how this method of instantiating variables and functions is called? I guess it's something like a class?